# Confusion about the tangent in a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I am reading a book on 3D graphics. Consider this image, which is a top-view in a 3d-coordinate system.

[image]

The author writes:

[image]

I am assuming the triangles he is referring to are formed by points $(0,0), (x,0), (x,z)$ and $(0,0), (x_p,0), (x_p,d)$.

So, to calculate the tangent in a triangle:

$$tan(\theta) = \frac{opposite}{adjacent}$$

I feel really stupid for asking this, but why is the line segment $(x,0),(x,z)$ (ie. opposite) considered to be $x$ and the line segment $(0,0),(x,0)$ (ie. adjacent) considered to be $z$?

Shouldn't it be:

$$\frac{z}{x} = \frac{d}{x_p}$$

Comment: yeah, so... If $\frac{z}{x}=\frac{d}{x_p}$ then $$\frac{x}{z}=\frac{x_p}{d}$$ as desired.

Comment: Oh wow. It's back to basics for me. Thanks for the prompt answer!

Comment: The two right triangles share the same acute angle (at $p^\prime$) and hence have the same set of three angles, and hence are congruent.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say which angle you choose as $\theta$. One choice makes this equation even more immediate than in the comments. But in my opinion, you should just identify the similar triangles and which sides correspond to each other and not talk about tangents.